# How to do a v-model for an array of objects with multiple fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have 2 checkbox inputs for each element in an array. The first represents a field in a form and the second represents the fact that the field is required or not, I need to construct and array of objects like so

```
    [
     {
      name: 'fieldName',
      required: true
     },
     {
      name: 'anotherFieldName'
     }
    ]
```

If the first checkbox is checked I need to add an object with the "name" property in my array, and if the second one is checked too I also need to add the "required" field.

Comment: Try using the key representing the object in the `v-for` loop

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <li v-for="(item, index) of items"> 
      {{ item.prop2 }} 
      <input type="text" v-model="items[index].prop2">
   </li>
```

or

```
<li v-for="(item, index) of items"> 
      {{ item.prop2 }} 
      <input type="text" @input="updateMyProp(index)">
</li>

   ...
   methods: {
     updateMyProp ($event, index) {
       // your update logic here
       // you can use 'this.items', Object.assign, Vue.set, etc... to update your value
     }
   ...
```